# Autocomplete behavior in Internet explorer and chrome

Tags: html, browser, kendo-ui, cross-browser, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I've been checking web application cross-browser compatibility and noticed few issues. One of the major issue was autocomplete.

When user enters something in input text, by default, IE will take auto-complete is on and fills the previously entered data. But in Chrome, its exact opposite. It won't retain previously entered data.

This is what I've observed for the above behavior in browsers.

- IE 11 -> Retains (even when auto-complete is off)
- Chrome 54 -> Retains
- Opera 38 -> Retains
- Firefox 52 -> Retains
- safari 5 (Windows) -> Retains

When I checked with Kendo UI control, for same browser, behavior changes like this.

- IE 11 -> No
- Chrome 54 -> No
- Opera 38 -> No
- Firefox 52 -> Yes
- safari 5 (Windows) -> No

If I need to ensure same behavior for all these browsers, what I'm supposed to do? Preferably for both Kendo UI and HTML5?

---

- [How to keep changed form content when leaving and going back to
  HTTPS page? (works with HTTP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420624/how-to-keep-changed-form-content-when-leaving-and-going-back-to-https-page-wor)
- [Configure Firefox to remember form changes when accidentally leaving a HTTPS page?](https://superuser.com/questions/539789/configure-firefox-to-remember-form-changes-when-accidentally-leaving-a-https-pag)
- [autocomplete attribute | autocomplete property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533486(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [autocomplete attribute | autocomplete property | For IE10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh968263(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Why worry of how different browser have implemented an auto-complete function? After all, it often can be switched of by the user. Do you mean you see conflicts with Kendo's Autocomplete?

If you want autocomplete all times and for all browsers, I would suggest implementing your own autocomplete with Kendo's control and not depend on how different browser handle these (or not). Or do I misunderstand your question?